# Do solvable groups have elementary abelian characteristic subgroups?

Tags: group-theory

I know that the minimal normal subgroup of a solvable group is elementary abelian, and that it is characteristically simple, but it isn't obvious to me that it is characteristic. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious?

EDIT: Since this is not the case do solvable groups have elementary abelian characteristic subgroups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the edited question is yes. As you say, a minimal normal subgroup of a (nontrivial) finite solvable group is an elementary abelian $p$-group for some prime $p$. If $N_1$ and $N_2$ are two of these (i.e. for the same fixed prime $p$), then by minimality $N_1 \cap N_2 = 1$, so $[N_1,N_2]=1$. Hence any two of them commute, and the subgroup $N$ generated by all minimal normal $p$-subgroups is itself elementary abelian, and it is characteristic.

Comment: What if $N_1$ and $N_2$ are elementary abelian for different primes, such as in the dihedral group of order $20$? Perhaps not the best example, since those individual minimal normals are themselves characteristic.  Could it occur that there are $N_1$ and $N_2$ for different primes where neither $N_i$ is characteristic?

Comment: I see now; you are specifically taking the $N_i$ to be $p$-groups for a single $p$.

Comment: Yes, I've edited to clarify that point.

Comment: @DerekHolt I'm not sure I see exactly why $[N_1, N_2] = 1$.

Comment: $[N_1,N_2] \le N_1 \cap N_2 = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Take a look at the Klein $4$-group, $C_2\times C_2$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Is there a characteristic subgroup of a finite solvable group $G$ which is both elementary abelian and characteristic in $G$, then?

Comment: Technically, the trivial subgroup works.  But I think you can grab a non-trivial one out of the last non-trivial term of the derived series.

Comment: But the whole group works here!(Oh I see, that answers the edited question, not the original.)